# How can i change the color of a material created with the PBR addon

Tags: materials

I have installed the PBR addon. With a Light sphere material applied, I want to change the color from white to red or something else. I can't find the color option to change. Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Here are the nodes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with PBR is: it tries to be physically accurate. That's why you don't have a RGB input in this setup but a blackbody converter node.

Blackbody converts color temperature (measured in kelvin) to RGB values.
You can look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) to see which color corresponds to which kelvin value.

if you don't need to be physically accurate, you can just unconnected the blackbody node and set the color directly in the emission shader.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either:

mix your Light Sphere emission output with another shader, that allows you to set the color (like diffuse)

-or-  add a MixRGB node to the Blackbody color output.